# Image saving in a loop in Python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, matplotlib, if-statement

I have an algorithm in python that goes like that:

```
For i in range(400,500):
 if(avg<50):
   plt.plot(x,y)
   plt.savefig(image.png)
 else:
   plt.plot(x1,y1)
   plt.savefig(image.png)
```

now, without the loop, i would have one saved plot. But at each iteration, I am using another array of data, thus a different plot appears. The problem I'm facing is that the figure saved keeps being replaced by the new one at the next iteration, and what i want is all the plots saved in one directory. Can anyone guide me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This requires that `x`, `y`, `x1` and `y1` be defined outside the loop

```py
for i in range(400,500):
  img_name = f"./image_{i}.png"
  if(avg<50):
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.savefig(img_name)
  else:
    plt.plot(x1,y1)
    plt.savefig(img_name)
```

One such solution might be to change the name for every iteration. The way I accomplished this was post-pending the image number.

This saves it into the current dir.